# Java: lifecycle of a variable within a method

Tags: java, class

first of all apologies if this questions has been already covered elsewhere. I'm a total beginner and some topics are way too complicated to me.

I declared the variable `'x=0`' in the beginning of the method and then used `for()` method where `'x'` was built up to 45.

When the block of `"for() {}"`ended on closing curly bracket why `'x'` still returned `45`? I thought the life cycle of`x` within the block will be ended on completion of for{}?

Could someone please clarify this?

Many thanks,

```
public class Demo4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;
        int x = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x += i;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean why `x` is not 0? You changed it's value within its scope. How did you get 45 from 10?

Comment: The sum of the integers from 0 to 9 is 45.

Answer (score 2):

A local variable exists from the point where it is declared to the end of the innermost enclosing block. It doesn't matter which constructs use the variable. In your case, `x` exists until the end of `main()`.

However, there's a special rule for `for` loops: if you declare a variable as a part of the `for` header, you'll achieve what you want, as the `x` will exist only during the loop execution:

```
for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x += i;
}
```

(Note that this also declares `i` inside the loop header; if you want it to be declared outside, you must also initialize it outside and only have `int x = 0` inside the loop header.)

Note that this is different from declaring a variable inside the loop *body*, as that variable will be reinitialized in each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = 0;
    x += i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lifecycle of a variable in the java stays in the block in which you declared the variable. You can consider the blocks inside a block as it's children block and the variable declared in the parent block will carry forward to the children block. But if you declare a variable in the inner(children) block than it can not be used in the outer(parent) block.

As in the below code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x = 0;
        x += i;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

If you use the above code it will give error. Since the x is declared in for loop block and it's scope only inside that block not outside it.

But the code you posted have x in the outer block and for loop is inside that block. So when you use it inside for loop it works.